# Facebook api get likes/shares/comments for shared link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook feed js api to share link. Something like this:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://mylink.com/page?param=value',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){});
```

After user share link i get some id in response. Looks like all OK.
But, how i can get likes/comments/reposts for this share?

I try to use graph api something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{{id}}
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{{userId}}_{{id}}
```

But nothing helped.

What is this strange id, that share js api returned, and where to use it? How get stats to share action?

Answer (score 0):

The number/id returned by the Graph API is the post or object's ID.

To get the likes or comments for that ID, you can use v2.2/{object_id}/likes or v2.2/{object_id}/comments. See the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes) for full details.

FYI, every time a link is shared on an user's wall, a new object is created, so you will get a different ID for each share.